# UIIButton IBAction will not work while using random numbers and setting images

Tags: ios, swift, random

I have a program i am working on that is supposed to output a random amount of dice each with a random side showing when the device is shaken.  I have gotten that part to work, but now I want to add in a button that when pressed selects one of the dice being sides being displayed as the only side being displayed.  I have the button added through my storyboard and this function sets some attributes:

```
func setButton(show: Bool = true) {
    if show == true{
        observerButton.setTitle("Observe", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        observerButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        observerButton.setTitleShadowColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }else{
        observerButton.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        observerButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.clearColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        observerButton.setTitleShadowColor(UIColor.clearColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

This function is used to enable the button after the device is shaken.  Here is the code in the IBAction:

```
@IBAction func observe(sender: UIButton) {
    if shaked == true{
        var chosenDice: Int = Int(arc4random()) % amountOfNumbers
        resetDice()
        dice[0].image = diceImages[diceDisplayed[chosenDice]-1]
        shaked = false
    }
}
```

diceImages is an array that contains an image of each side of a die.  amountOfNumbers is generated in another function and is a random number from 1-6 and is used to tell how many dice will be displayed.  resetDice() sets all of the dice to "nil" and shaked is set to true after the device is shaken (kind of obvious but I just wanted to cover everything).  Dice is my IBOutlet array for the UIImageViews where the dice are displayed.

When I run this program, everything runs fine, but as soon as I push the button, the app stops (doesn't crash entirely, but Xcode comes into my view and the button code is not visibly executed) with the error,

```
"EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)"
```

next to the close bracket of the if statement in the observe IBAction function, and it says in the console, "(lldb)"  There are no syntax errors.

I know arc4random_uniform() will not work instead of the arc4random() % amountOfNumbers because that function requires a UInt32 where amountOfNumbers is an Int.

Comment: I changed random() to arc4random() and still got the same result.  I also tested moving the `%` to a different line and the error resulted on that line.

Comment: I fixed the error with the remainder operator by separating the lines, but the same error at the closing bracket of the if statement still occurs.

Comment: I changed up the button action function a little and it now looks like this: 

`@IBAction func observerButton(sender: UIButton) {
        var chosenDice = Int(arc4random())
        chosenDice = chosenDice % amountOfNumbers
        setButton(show: false)
        resetDice()
        dice[0].image = diceImages[diceDisplayed[chosenDice]-1]
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {self.dice[0].alpha = 1})
        shaked=false
    }`
 
With the setting of dice[0] the app fails each time, but without it it fails at seemingly random times.  I am very confused and need help!

Comment: Also without setting `shaked=false` or setting dice[0] the program works every time.

Comment: I tried putting the code into a separate function and calling it when the button is pressed to see if it was a problem with the IBAction but the same error occurred at the closing bracket of the separate function I created.

Comment: The occurrence of the error is not always consistent, there have been times when the program will work fine but when the button is pressed again the error occurs.  I have not been able to find a pattern with this.

Comment: I added a println to tell me what number was chosen to be outputted, and when the app failed the number was not one of the dice being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arc4random()` can generate values that are too high to fit inside a normal Int, which is why their default type is`UInt32`, so they can store values that large.  Exceeding the limit of the Int resulted in the error.  I fixed this by changing the `arc4random()` to a rand() which created smaller values that could fit inside an Int.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the `random()` line.

Try this instead:

```
var chosenDice = arc4random_uniform(amountOfNumbers)
```

Comment: This will not work because arc4random_uniform() requires a UInt32 type and amountOfNumbers is an Int, I used Int(arc4random_uniform(6))+1 to generate numbers from 1 to 6 to generate the number for amountOfNumbers.  I do believe it may be that line however because I remember encountering the same error while not having the entire function complete.  I tried adding a :Int to chosenDice and got the same result.

Comment: What about arc4random_uniform(UInt32(amountOfNumbers)) then?

Comment: From what I can tell it is impossible to convert amountOfNumbers into a UInt32 as the error says UInt32 is not convertible to Int.  I have tried other methods to do this as well.  amountOfNumbers cannot be changed to a UInt32 though because I must use it as an Int in other areas.